# 700 Google Crawl Errors caused by AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, server-error

I added a new feature to a site recently, which uses AJAX to load Log-in and Registration panels.

After uploading I got tons of Google Crawl Errors, nearly 700!

The error URL doesn't appear anywhere in the source of the page, except as the URL used by a jQuery **.load()** function.

Could it be that Google is trying to crawl the URL being used by my JavaScript code?

Comment: Google seems to have a way of crawling a lot of URLs that I never intended for it to crawl, so quite possibly, yes.

Comment: Thanks, is the a way of stopping Google from doing this? I'm guessing robots.txt?

Comment: I agree with Thunder Rabbit.  I have even seen the googlebot 'guess' at things that it thinks are possible urls.

Comment: Do you think I'm getting penalized for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this page from the Google Docs  http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174993  It gives you some ideas about ajax and how to prevent the bot from messing with your ajax stuff.  Specifically the "What if my site has some hash fragment URLs that should not be crawled?" question.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look into that. As a side note, dose Google penalize your site for internal server errors? My error code is 500.

Comment: People speculate that you are being penalized for 500 errors.  I could not find anything that specifically said "we penalize" for 500's ( see their Webmaster Guidelines -->  http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35769 ) but it would stand to reason that they do, since they penalize for spelling mistakes, W3C validity and a whole host of other little things.  In the end, the only people who really know work for Google and they won't tell you how much you are being affected by those 500's.

Comment: more on the aside: if you are interested in how the googlebot sees your site, use this  https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/  it shows DNS errors, server connectivity errors and all kinds of stuff.